# Masking only on shapefile geometry in cartopy

Tags: data-science, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas, cartopy

I interpolated temperature data observed on an urban area formed by 12 locations. Now i would like to remove all interpolated values that are outside the shapefile layer. How can i do it?

The shapefile links:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u76k3yegvr09sx/LimiteAMG.shp?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxsmm3v2ey3ngsp/LimiteAMG.cpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx05n31dfkggbb6/LimiteAMG.dbf?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6nk0xczgjeen2d/LimiteAMG.prj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/royw7s51n2f0a6x/LimiteAMG.qpj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k44dcl1k5891qc/LimiteAMG.shx?dl=0

The Data is:

```
         Lat       Lon     T
   0   20.8208 -103.4434  22.0
   1   20.7019 -103.4728  21.9
   2   20.6833 -103.3500  24.2
   3   20.6280 -103.4261   NaN
   4   20.7205 -103.3172  25.7
   5   20.7355 -103.3782  24.0
   6   20.6593 -103.4136   NaN
   7   20.6740 -103.3842  25.0
   8   20.7585 -103.3904  23.0
   9   20.6230 -103.4265   NaN
   10  20.6209 -103.5004  20.0
   11  20.6758 -103.6439  26.8
   12  20.7084 -103.3901  24.4
   13  20.6353 -103.3994  23.1
   14  20.5994 -103.4133  23.0
   15  20.6302 -103.3422  24.0
   16  20.7400 -103.3122  25.3
   17  20.6061 -103.3475   NaN
   18  20.6400 -103.2900  23.9
   19  20.7248 -103.5305  22.2
   20  20.6238 -103.2401   NaN
   21  20.4400 -103.4200  22.0
   22  20.7700 -103.3900  21.0
   23  20.7000 -103.4300  25.0
   24  20.7100 -103.3700  25.0
   25  20.7000 -103.3700  25.0
   26  20.6700 -103.3900  23.0
   27  20.6700 -103.3200  23.0
   28  20.6600 -103.4400  26.0
   29  20.6300 -103.4800  23.0
   30  20.6200 -103.4800  21.0
   31  20.9301 -103.4316  23.0
```

The code is:

```
  import cartopy.crs as ccrs
  from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  from metpy.calc import get_wind_components
  from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
  from metpy.gridding.gridding_functions import interpolate,remove_nan_observations
  from metpy.plots import add_metpy_logo
  from metpy.units import units

  #Definir proyeccion
  to_proj = ccrs.AlbersEqualArea(central_longitude=-103.0,central_latitude=20.0)

  #Leer datos obervados
  data = pd.read_csv('/home/borisvladimir/Documentos/Datos/EMAs/EstacionesZMG/RedZMG.csv', header=0, usecols=(3, 4, 5),names=['Lat', 'Lon', 'T'],na_values=-99999)

  #Transforma las coordenadas
  lon = data['Lon'].values
  lat = data['Lat'].values
  xp, yp, _ = to_proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lon, lat).T

  #Configura datos nulos
  x_masked, y_masked, t = remove_nan_observations(xp, yp, data['T'].values)

  #Configura interpolacion radial
  tempx, tempy, temp = interpolate(x_masked, y_masked, t, interp_type='rbf', hres=100, rbf_func='linear',rbf_smooth=0.5)
  temp = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(temp), temp)

  #Leer archivo shapefile
  fname='/home/borisvladimir/Dropbox/Diversos/Shapes/DistritosZap.shp'
  adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())

  #Configura proyeccion
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 7))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=to_proj)

  #Agrega geometrias del shapefile
  ax.add_geometries(adm1_shapes,ccrs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black', facecolor='none', alpha=0.5)

  #Configura resolucion del mapa
  ax.set_extent([-103.60, -103.29, 20.54,20.93 ])

  #Agrega etiquetas al mapa
CopaLon,CopaLat=-103.4288,20.8595
TesisLon,TesisLat=-103.5344,20.7857
NixtLon,NixtLat=-103.4043,20.7938
AireLon,AireLat=-103.4922,20.7482
TuzaLon,TuzaLat=-103.4355,20.7333
RobLon,RobLat=-103.4082,20.7576
ArroLon,ArroLat=-103.3540,20.7555
CentroLon,CentroLat=-103.3870,20.7251
VallaLon,VallaLat=-103.4297,20.6834
ColiLon,ColiLat=-103.4634,20.6379
AguiLon,AguiLat=-103.4198,20.6373
TepeLon,TepeLat=-103.4592,20.6062
  plt.plot([CopaLon,TesisLon,NixtLon,AireLon,TuzaLon,RobLon,ArroLon,CentroLon,VallaLon,ColiLon,AguiLon,TepeLon],[CopaLat,TesisLat,NixtLat,AireLat,TuzaLat,RobLat,ArroLat,CentroLat,VallaLat,ColiLat,AguiLat,TepeLat],'bo', markersize=2,transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.text(CopaLon-0.0138,CopaLat+0.0098,'Copala',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TesisLon,TesisLat,'Tesistan',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(NixtLon-0.0138,NixtLat+0.0098,'Nixticuil',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(AireLon-0.0259,AireLat+0.0084,'Base Aerea',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TuzaLon-0.0138,TuzaLat+0.007,'Tuzania',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(RobLon-0.0359,RobLat+0.005,'Los Robles',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(ArroLon-0.0138,ArroLat+0.007,'Arrollo Hondo',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(CentroLon-0.0138,CentroLat+0.007,'Centro',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(VallaLon-0.0138,VallaLat+0.007,'Patria',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(ColiLon-0.0138,ColiLat+0.007,'El Coli',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(AguiLon-0.0138,AguiLat+0.007,'Las Aguilas',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TepeLon-0.0138,TepeLat+0.007,'Tepetitan',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.title('Temperaturas maximas observadas en Zapopan\n8-Feb-2018')
#Configura paleta de colores
levels = list(range(20, 29, 1))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

mmb = ax.pcolormesh(tempx, tempy, temp, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(mmb, shrink=.4, pad=0.02, boundaries=levels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062299/2454357) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626078/2454357).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting shapefile using LineCollection shows all edges, but partially fills them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015378/plotting-shapefile-using-linecollection-shows-all-edges-but-partially-fills-the)