# Plotting a masked Antarctica with a shapefile or geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap, geopandas

I'm trying to plot data around the Antarctica while masking the continent. While I'm using `basemap` and it has an option to easily mask continents using `map.fillcontinents()`, the continent considered by `basemap` includes the ice shelves, which I do not want to mask.

I tried using `geopandas` from a code I found on the Internet. This works, except the coastline produces an undesired line in what I assume is the beginning/end of the polygon for the Antarctica:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
from descartes import PolygonPatch

lats = np.arange(-90,-59,1)
lons = np.arange(0,361,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
data = np.random.rand(len(lats),len(lons))

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

fig=plt.figure(dpi=150)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

m = Basemap(projection='spstere',boundinglat=-60,lon_0=180,resolution='i',round=True)  
xi, yi = m(X,Y)

cf = m.contourf(xi,yi,data)

patches = []
selection = world[world.name == 'Antarctica']
for poly in selection.geometry:
    if poly.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        mpoly = shapely.ops.transform(m, poly)
        patches.append(PolygonPatch(mpoly))
    elif poly.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        for subpoly in poly:
            mpoly = shapely.ops.transform(m, poly)
            patches.append(PolygonPatch(mpoly))
    else:
        print(poly, 'blah')
ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True,color='w',edgecolor='k'))
```

[image: Geopandas output]

The same line appears when I try to use other shapefiles, such as the *land* one that is available to download for free from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/). So I edited this shapefile in QGIS to remove the borders of the Antarctica. The problem now is that I don't know how to mask everything that's *inside* the shapefile (and couldn't find how to do it either). I also tried combining the previous code with `geopandas` by setting the `linewidth=0`, and adding on top the shapefile I created. The problem is that they are not exactly the same:

[image: Bad borders when using geopandas and shapefile]

Any suggestion on how to mask using a shapefile, or with geopandas but without the line?

Edit: Using Thomas Khün's previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015378/plotting-shapefile-using-linecollection-shows-all-edges-but-partially-fills-the/48062299#48062299) with my edited shapefile produces a well masked Antarctica/continents, but the coastline goes outside the round edges of the map:

[image: outside edges]

I uploaded [here](https://ufile.io/x8scg) the edited shapefile I used, but it's the [Natural Earth Data 50m land shapefile](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_land.zip) without the line.

Comment: Why don't you use your edited shapefile to mask out Antarctica? Can you show the code you use to plot the outline with your edited shapefile?

Comment: @ThomasKühn I don't know how to use my edited shapefile to mask out Antarctica. I just plot the outline of the shapefile by using `basemap's readshapefile`:             `m.readshapefile('myshpfile_location', 'myshpfile_name',color='k',linewidth=0.6)`. It does not have an option (or couldn't find it) such as `facecolor`.

Comment: Could you have a look if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062299/2454357) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626078/2454357) helps you? If not, please provide your shapefile and I can try to write up an answer for you.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I edited the post to show what happens when I try to use your first answer. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example of how to achieve what you want. I basically followed the [Basemap example](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html) how to deal with `shapefiles` and added a bit of [shapely magic](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) to restrict the outlines to the map boundaries. Note that I first tried to extract the map outline from `ax.patches`, but that somehow didn't work, so I defined a circle which has a radius of `boundinglat` and transformed it using the Basemap coordinate transformation functionality.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon as sPolygon

boundinglat = -40 
lats = np.arange(-90,boundinglat+1,1)
lons = np.arange(0,361,1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
data = np.random.rand(len(lats),len(lons))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, dpi=150)

m = Basemap(
    ax = ax,
    projection='spstere',boundinglat=boundinglat,lon_0=180,
    resolution='i',round=True
)  
xi, yi = m(X,Y)

cf = m.contourf(xi,yi,data)

#adjust the path to the shapefile here:
result = m.readshapefile(
    'shapefiles/AntarcticaWGS84_contorno', 'antarctica',
    zorder = 10, color = 'k', drawbounds = False)

#defining the outline of the map as shapely Polygon:
rim = [np.linspace(0,360,100),np.ones(100)*boundinglat,]
outline = sPolygon(np.asarray(m(rim[0],rim[1])).T)

#following Basemap tutorial for shapefiles
patches = []
for info, shape in zip(m.antarctica_info, m.antarctica):
    #instead of a matplotlib Polygon, create first a shapely Polygon
    poly = sPolygon(shape)
    #check if the Polygon, or parts of it are inside the map:
    if poly.intersects(outline):
        #if yes, cut and insert
        intersect = poly.intersection(outline)        
        verts = np.array(intersect.exterior.coords.xy)
        patches.append(Polygon(verts.T, True))

ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(
    patches, facecolor= 'w', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2
))

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: the result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still trying to figure out a simple way to mask a grid from a shapefile, here is a [gallery example](https://antarctic-plots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/mask_from_shp.html) from the python package [Antarctic-Plots](https://antarctic-plots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which makes this simple.

```
from antarctic_plots import maps, fetch, utils
import pyogrio

# fetch a grid and shapefile
grid = fetch.bedmachine(layer='surface')
shape = fetch.groundingline()

# subset the grounding line from the coastline
gdf = pyogrio.read_dataframe(shape)
groundingline = gdf[gdf.Id_text == "Grounded ice or land"]

# plot the grid
fig = maps.plot_grd(grid)

# plot the shapefile
fig.plot(groundingline, pen='1p,red')
fig.show()
```

[image]

```
# mask the inside region
masked_inside = utils.mask_from_shp(
    shapefile=groundingline, xr_grid=grid, masked=True)

masked_inside.plot()
```

[image]

```
# mask the outside region
masked_outside = utils.mask_from_shp(
    shapefile=groundingline, xr_grid=grid, masked=True, invert=False)

masked_outside.plot()
```

[image]